# How to switch from wifi n/w to gprs programmaticaly in android?

Tags: android, networking, sockets, wifi, gprs

How can I forcefully send data packets over gprs n/w eventhough wifi is on?

How to create socket for gprs n/w in Android and to know gprs ip?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you explain your use case someone may be able to come up with an alternate approach and solution.

Comment: have you found an answer for this ?